# How to turnoff Spark session builder logs

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

Check the below-attached screenshot and I have marked logs in red color. These are all the logs we get when the Spark session is created. I would like to disable the same.
How to turn off the spark session logs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the log level

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
Logger.getLogger(“org.apache”).setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Comment: Yes, but no luck